# Repository pattern, different identifiers

Tags: design-patterns, repository

**TLDR;** I have one repo interface and multiple data sources, each with a different data identifier - how can I maintain having only one method in my interface?

I have a need to read a domain object `OrderData` from two different repositories: one is an outside service and the other one is a local database. 
Let's call them `OutsideServiceOrderRepo` and `LocalDbOrderRepo`. 
They both implement an interface called `IOrderRepoRead`:

```
Interface IOrderRepoRead
  +GetOrder(OrderEntityData) : Order
```

I'll never use both implementations in the same use case, it's an either/or situation. I have sorted out how to inject one or the other repo at the composition root, depending on the use case.
The problem I have is that each of these data stores has a different identifier for the data I'm after:

- Local store has a simple `OrderId` that I have within my system.
- External service requires me to query using a person's `Tax_number+Name+what_not` etc...

The ideas I came up with so far are as follows:

1. I have a type called `OrderEntityData` with properties `TaxNumber`, `Name`, `OrderId`. Both implementations can use this type, each implementation works with the properties it requires: `OutsideServiceOrderRepo` uses `TaxNumber`, `Name`, whereas `LocalDbOrderRepo` uses `OrderId`.
2. I drop the `OrderEntityData` and have two different methods in my `IOrderRepoRead`.

.

```
Interface IOrderRepoRead
  +GetOrder(taxNumber, name, whatNot) : Order
  +GetOrder(orderId) : Order
```

I'm inclined to go with approach #1, but it still feels like there is a certain amount of coupling among the repo and client code.

How can I efficiently alternate between different identifiers?

Comment: The client code still needs to know about which data-source is being used by repository. Does the client know about it?

Comment: No, all the decisioning on which data source to use is implemented on back-end. Client just submits from various apps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Software Engineering, but I can't recommend moving it there since there is no option offered.

Comment: Do you mean sending OrderEntityData from client, couples client to the Repo?